# openAPI dart generator from java spring-boot does not generate null safety code

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, dart, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using openAPI with a Java spring-boot server to generate client code for a flutter mobile application. The generator I am using is `dart`.

The generated code does not seem to have null safety. All the model properties are nullable and every request returns an nullable optional value, which forces to put `!` everywhere in my code. I am using the adequate Lombok anotations for null safety such as @NonNull. Is this normal?

Here is an example of a generated data class:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationResponse {
    @NonNull
    public User user;
    @NonNull
    public boolean isNewUser;
}
```

```dart
class RegistrationResponse {
  /// Returns a new [RegistrationResponse] instance.
  RegistrationResponse({
    this.user,
    this.isNewUser,
  });

  ///
  /// Please note: This property should have been non-nullable! Since the specification file
  /// does not include a default value (using the "default:" property), however, the generated
  /// source code must fall back to having a nullable type.
  /// Consider adding a "default:" property in the specification file to hide this note.
  ///
  Users? user;

  /// same comment
  ///
  bool? isNewUser;
//...
};
```

Why do I need to have a default value for the property to be nullable?